# How do I add two arrays together and collect ids where one or both can be null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a method where I add two arrays together and collect their IDs.  The problem is, it's possible for one or both arrays to be null.

This is what I have:

```
all_items = old_duplicate_items.to_a + new_duplicate_items.to_a
all_items.map(&:id) unless all_items.blank?
```

Can this be improved upon?

Comment: Show us samples of the input arrays, and what you expect the resulting array to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're ok with an empty array as a result in the case of both input arrays being `nil`, then you could consolidate it as follows:

```
(old_duplicate_items.to_a + new_duplicate_items.to_a).map(&:id)
```

but that's about all I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks pretty good. Right now, it returns nil or a populated Array. If it's OK to return an empty array, you could try:

```
(old_duplicate_items.to_a + new_duplicate_items.to_a).map &:id
```

To preserve the nil return would require something at least as complex as what you have now:

```
(x = old_duplicate_items.to_a + new_duplicate_items.to_a).size > 0 ? x : nil
```

Or perhaps:

```
if (x = old_duplicate_items.to_a + new_duplicate_items.to_a).size > 0; x end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
all_items = ((old_duplicate_items || []).to_a + (new_duplicate_items || []).to_a).map(&:id)
```

Comment: I think the `|| []` operations are unnecessary, because `.to_a` will convert `nil` to an empty array, as I assume the OP realized.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin You're right. Wasn't sure about that myself so I just added them in.